# Multiple FieldConstructor in PlayFramework 2.1?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

I am trying to build a custom FieldConstructor in the scala doc.

I follow the instruction , build a `twitterBootstrapInput.scala.html` , 
and it works ...

This is my output :

[image: output screenshot]

Here comes the problem :

I want the `@helper.inputRadioGroup` spans "horizontally" , not vertically.

(Because `twitterBootstrapInput.scala.html` warps `@elements.input` in `<div>` block )

But I don't know how to modify the template without infecting other "textfields" ?

Should I define another implicitFieldConstructor ? Or do something else ?

I cannot find an example about how to solve this problem ...

All the custom template documents are too rare...

Can somebody give me an example ? Thanks !

This is my code (play 2.1) :

```
@import views.html.helper.FieldConstructor
@implicitFieldConstructor = @{ FieldConstructor(twitterBootstrapInput.f) }

@helper.inputRadioGroup(consultForm("currency") 
  , options = Seq(
    "USD" -> "USD" 
  , "HKD" -> "HKD" 
  , "RMB" -> "RMB") 
  , '_label -> "Currency" 
  , '_error -> consultForm("currency").error.map(_.withMessage("select currency"))
)
```

======== April/11 updated ==============

Thanks @Schleichardt for giving me a first step. I append `(FieldConstructor(twitterBootstrapRadioGroup.f) , lang)` after the `inputRadioGroup` , it seems working. But , even I write the simplest `@elements.input` in the template (no other decorations) , it still spans vertically. As the following screenshot :

[image]

And the output html source code is :

[image]

How to modify the `<span class="buttonset" ...>` block ? 
Shouldn't I call `@elements.input` in the template ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short version:**

```
@(consultForm: Form[Consult])(implicit lang: play.api.i18n.Lang)

@import views.html.helper.FieldConstructor
@implicitFieldConstructor = @{ FieldConstructor(twitterBootstrapInput.f) }

@* uses twitterBootstrapInput */
@helper.inputText(consultForm("name"))

@* uses anotherFieldConstructor */
@helper.inputRadioGroup(consultForm("currency") 
  , options = Seq(
    "USD" -> "USD" 
  , "HKD" -> "HKD" 
  , "RMB" -> "RMB") 
  , '_label -> "Currency" 
  , '_error -> consultForm("currency").error.map(_.withMessage("select currency"))
)(FieldConstructor(anotherFieldConstructor.f), lang)


@* uses twitterBootstrapInput */
@helper.inputText(consultForm("anotherFormFieldName"))
```

`anotherFieldConstructor` is an additional FieldConstructor you have to create. It should place the radio buttons according your needs.

**Long version:**

The API DOC for inputRadioGroup is here: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.1.0/scala/index.html#views.html.helper.inputRadioGroup$

Since inputRadioGroup is a Scala singleton object the following code statements are the same:

```
helper.inputRadioGroup(consultForm("currency") /* etc. */)
helper.inputRadioGroup.apply(consultForm("currency") /* etc. */)
```

The apply method of inputRadioGroup has two parameter lists. The second list uses implicit parameters.

With `@implicitFieldConstructor = @{ FieldConstructor(twitterBootstrapInput.f) }` you specified, that the `twitterBootstrapInput` FieldConstructor is the "default parameter" for handler in the second parameter list of inputRadioGroup.

But you can overwrite it with explicit parameters:

```
helper.inputRadioGroup(consultForm("currency") /* etc. */)(FieldConstructor(anotherFieldConstructor.f), lang)
```

If you use Scala controllers the template needs an additional parameter list for lang:

```
@(consultForm: Form[Consult)])(implicit lang: play.api.i18n.Lang)
```

You can't have two implict FieldConstructors in a template.

Comment: Hi , thanks for instructing me the first step. But the output still spans vertically. How to modify the `@elements.input` template ? (I've updated my question , appending code and screenshot)

Comment: @smallufo I would guess that's a CSS issue at that point. The `<label>`'s probably have a `display:block` rule or something that's forcing them to go to a separate line.

Comment: Thanks , it works. After overriding the display:block to display:inline , the radios spans horizontally. But I still wonder how to modify the 'elements.input' template ? any documents ?

Comment: @smallufo oh, I see what you're asking. No, what you want to do is write your own inputRadioGroup template. Those are the ones that get included into the field constructor templates at the `@elements.input`. Take a look at the link below, just copy that file, make your modifications, and use it instead of `helper.inputRadioGroup`.

https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/2.1.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/helper/inputRadioGroup.scala.html

Comment: Thanks @estmatic , it seems that all helper.XXXs are just one implementations of html element, and I can define myself's myHelper.inputRadioGroup , right ?

Comment: @smallufo That's right, they define the HTML form element itself and the field constructor defines the HTML that wraps it.